# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 4.11.0-13-generic

Tags: kernel

I need this Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 4.11.0-13-generic ISO, can someone guide me where/how to download?

It because Symantec say:

Supported Linux kernels for Endpoint Protection 14.x

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.INFO3983.html

So i can't use Ubuntu 16.04 4.13.0-43-generic (Download from 
Ubuntu website)

Anyone can guide where to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 4.11.0-13-generic ISO.

Thank you

Comment: 4.11 is not a supported kernel for Ubuntu; it does not get patched by Canonical so you need to patch fixes yourself. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with 4.4 by default, and with HWE (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) 4.15 is the current default (though security fixes are backported to 4.4 too as its still supported)   The Symantec page you listed is very out-of-date .  (12.04 reached EOL in 2017, 15.10 in 2016...)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu 16.04.1 with the 4.4 kernel.

You can download images from [HERE](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/)

The 4.4 kernel still gets security updates. I don't recomment to install the 4.11 kernel.